# Hardware Decoding suddenly stopped working for Steam In-Home Streaming?

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, steam

Steam In-Home streaming suddenly started refusing to use hardware decoding. Have been using this for some time without issue. The client PC is too weak for software decoding.

Running Steam Client on Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit with nvidia-384 drivers, and a GT710.

Have tried reinstalling steam and nvidia drivers to no avail. Keeps defaulting back to software decoding.

Started steam from a shell, and noticed this in the output when streaming a game:

```
ffmpeg verbose: Opened VA display via X11 display :0.
libva info: VA-API version 0.39.0`
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/nvidia_drv_video.so
libva info: va_openDriver() returns -1
ffmpeg error: Failed to initialise VAAPI connection: -1 (unknown libva error).
CVAAPIAccel: av_hwdevice_ctx_create() failed
libavcodec software decoding with 2 threads
```

Sure enough, there is no `nvidia_drv_video.so` present. At a complete loss here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, apparently something did get removed. Ran `sudo apt-get install vdpau-va-driver:i386`. Now all is well.

For anyone else wondering, `dpkg -S /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/nvidia_drv_video.so` showed the package that needed to be installed.

**Edit 11/25/2018**:
This behavior persists on a new install of 16.04, the same steps were needed to remedy the issue.